# New tags for MGs please

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

May I ask for some new tags for `MG` and `ZS-180` I would like `MG-ZS-180` but I know that does not fit the pattern of the site at the moment and I don't have the rep. I also apologize now for the blatant plagiarism but the text is as much for inspiration then anything (my spelling and knowledge is limited).

`MG` could read `The MG Car Company Limited was a British manufacturer founded in 1924`

`ZS` could be `The MG ZS is a sports family car. The ZS is essentially a tuned version of the Rover 45`

`ZS-180` could be `The MG ZS 180 with a 2.5-litre V6 engine was available as a 5-door hatch or a 4-door saloon`

also (off topic), what is the difference between `tags` and `tagging` tags, sorry but I picked both.

Comment: Added your tags

Comment: I saw that thanks! I Am grinning like a Cheshire cat right now

Answer (score 3):

Tags are words you associate with a question.  Look at the bottom of the questions and you will see tags.  You can add tags at the time you ask a question or afterword.  You can add tags to other peoples question when your reputation increases.

Tagging is the act of adding a tag to the question.

Comment: This is all true, but you have to have enough rep to create *new* tags ... I bet you realize that, but didn't mention it.